# Execute Discord with server invite

Tags: c#, discord

I was wondering if anyone knows whether it's possible to execute discord from C# with a server invite through Processes (from System.Diagnostics), and how you'd do that.

I've tried several things but none of them seem to work.
Hope anyone can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can.  In fact, you should check out their [developer documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro) page.  Along with that, there are samples and a C# wrapper class already built, called [DSharpPlus](https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/).  Have fun with it!

Comment: Thank you, I could only find Discord.Net but that one feels like it's more focused on building bots for Discord.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found what I was actually looking for!
By passing this url into the browser `discord:///invite-proxy/SERVERID`you can have users click a button and instantly join your server without opening the browser.